How should I work with Google Asset Bundle in Unity Editor?
I have a scene that contains UI elements. I’m currently loading UI assets from Asset Bundle so there is no assigned sprite reference in that scene. When I try to modify UI views I’m always assigning all the assets by manuel and deleting the references after the modification.
And this is frustrating.
Are there any solution for that?
I tried to assign them with ContextMenu function that I created but it didn't worked because AssetBundle only works in runtime in my case.
